# Weird href behaviour in navbar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

so I changed my href in navbar from mailto: to an external page link and it works only on desktop screens, on smaller screens where menu is opened using burger icon it still leads to mailto: even tho it does not exist in the code. I thought I might have missed to change a href somewhere but it is impossible since I used Find and Replace.

Source code:

````
        class="md:mt-1 inline-block float-right mr-4 hover:opacity-70"
        onclick="mobileMenu();"
      >
        <button id="three-lines">
          <svg
            width="40"
            height="40"
            viewBox="0 0 40 40"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <rect width="40" height="40" rx="8" fill="#2A3441" />
            <path
              d="M12.5714 15.5714H27.4286C27.7143 15.5714 28 15.3214 28 15V13.5714C28 13.2857 27.7143 13 27.4286 13H12.5714C12.25 13 12 13.2857 12 13.5714V15C12 15.3214 12.25 15.5714 12.5714 15.5714ZM12.5714 21.2857H27.4286C27.7143 21.2857 28 21.0357 28 20.7143V19.2857C28 19 27.7143 18.7143 27.4286 18.7143H12.5714C12.25 18.7143 12 19 12 19.2857V20.7143C12 21.0357 12.25 21.2857 12.5714 21.2857ZM12.5714 27H27.4286C27.7143 27 28 26.75 28 26.4286V25C28 24.7143 27.7143 24.4286 27.4286 24.4286H12.5714C12.25 24.4286 12 24.7143 12 25V26.4286C12 26.75 12.25 27 12.5714 27Z"
              fill="#718298"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <button id="x-button" class="hidden">
          <svg
            width="40"
            height="40"
            viewBox="0 0 40 40"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <rect width="40" height="40" rx="8" fill="#2A3441" />
            <path
              d="M22.2638 19.983L25.6681 16.5787C26.1106 16.1702 26.1106 15.4894 25.6681 15.0809L24.9191 14.3319C24.5106 13.8894 23.8298 13.8894 23.4213 14.3319L20.017 17.7362L16.5787 14.3319C16.1702 13.8894 15.4894 13.8894 15.0809 14.3319L14.3319 15.0809C13.8894 15.4894 13.8894 16.1702 14.3319 16.5787L17.7362 19.983L14.3319 23.4213C13.8894 23.8298 13.8894 24.5106 14.3319 24.9191L15.0809 25.6681C15.4894 26.1106 16.1702 26.1106 16.5787 25.6681L20.017 22.2638L23.4213 25.6681C23.8298 26.1106 24.5106 26.1106 24.9191 25.6681L25.6681 24.9191C26.1106 24.5106 26.1106 23.8298 25.6681 23.4213L22.2638 19.983Z"
              fill="#718298"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="imgs/separator.png" class="lg:hidden w-full" />
    <div
      class="hidden bg-fieldblack pt-6 pl-6 w-screen h-screen"
      id="mobile-menu"
    >
      <div class="mb-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div onclick="productsDropdown()">
            <p
              class="cursor-pointer droptitle hover:text-primary font-bold text-base text-graylight inline-block"
            >
              Products
              <object class="pointer-events-none inline-block align-middle">
                <img src="imgs/icn-arrow-down.png" />
              </object>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="productsDropdownMob"
            class="dropcontent bg-transparent rounded-[8px]"
          >
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/products">Overview</a>
            </p>
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/payroll">Payroll</a>
            </p>
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/vesting">Vesting</a>
            </p>
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/multisig">Multisig</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div onclick="casesDropdown()">
            <p
              class="cursor-pointer droptitle hover:text-primary font-bold text-base text-graylight inline-block"
            >
              Use Cases
              <object class="pointer-events-none inline-block align-middle">
                <img src="imgs/icn-arrow-down.png" />
              </object>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="casesDropdownMob"
            class="dropcontent bg-transparent rounded-[8px]"
          >
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/gamefi">Gaming</a>
            </p>
            <p
              class="text-graylight font-bold text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/nft">NFT</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1
          class="text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold hover:text-primary"
        >
          <a href="https://docs.streamflow.finance/" target="_blank">
            Documentation
          </a>
          <svg
            class="inline-block align-super"
            width="8"
            height="8"
            viewBox="0 0 8 8"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M0.4379 1.28891C0.4379 1.6194 0.702293 1.85075 1.01626 1.86727L4.91605 1.76813L0.173508 6.51067C-0.0578359 6.74201 -0.0578359 7.0725 0.173508 7.30385L0.702293 7.83263C0.917112 8.04745 1.26413 8.06398 1.49547 7.83263L6.23801 3.09009L6.13887 6.95683C6.13887 7.28732 6.38673 7.53519 6.7007 7.55171H7.42778C7.74175 7.53519 7.98962 7.28732 7.98962 6.98988V0.54531C7.98962 0.247868 7.74175 0 7.44431 0L0.999735 0C0.702293 0 0.454425 0.247868 0.4379 0.561834V1.28891Z"
              fill="#18A2D9"
            />
          </svg>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1
          class="text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold hover:text-primary hidden"
        >
          <a href="#about"> About </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1
          class="text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold hover:text-primary"
        >
          <a href="https://streamflow.finance/integrations"> Integrations </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1 class="text-base text-graylight font-bold hover:text-primary">
          <a
            href="https://streamflow.notion.site/Streamflow-Job-Board-public-019665299d73485e9098087ccf5ebe7c#a407431cbc6e4651bf28fecc70126e93"
            target="_blank"
          >
            Careers
          </a>
          <p class="inline-block align-top font-bold text-xs mb-2 text-primary">
            Hiring
          </p>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1 class="text-base text-graylight font-bold hover:text-primary">
          <a
            href="https://streamflow.finance/contact"
            target="_blank"
            id="mail"
          >
            Contact
          </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-8">
        <h1 class="text-base text-graylight font-bold hover:text-primary">
          <a href="https://discord.gg/ZC7URcQyM7" target="_blank"> Discord </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-base text-graylight font-bold hover:text-primary">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/streamflow_fi" target="_blank">
            Twitter
          </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="z-50 relative bg-fieldblack">
        <div class="hidden lg:flex items-center p-6">
          <a href="https://streamflow.finance" target="_blank">
            <img
              src="imgs/streamflow-logo-desktop.PNG"
              alt="StreamFlow Finance logo"
              class="sm:hidden lg:block cursor-pointer hover:opacity-70"
            />
          </a>
          <div class="w-fit">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div onclick="productsDropdown()">
                <p
                  class="cursor-pointer productsdroptitle hover:text-primary font-bold text-base text-graylight inline-block"
                >
                  Products
                  <object class="pointer-events-none inline-block align-middle">
                    <img src="imgs/icn-arrow-down.png" />
                  </object>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="productsDropdown"
                class="productsdropcontent bg-graydark rounded-[8px] mt-2"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/products">Overview</a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-4"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/payroll">Payroll</a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="pt-4 text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/vesting">Vesting</a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="pt-4 text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pb-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/multisig">Multisig</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:ml-4 xl:ml-8">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div onclick="casesDropdown()" class="w-auto">
                <p
                  class="cursor-pointer droptitle hover:text-primary font-bold text-base text-graylight inline-block"
                >
                  Use Cases
                  <object class="pointer-events-none inline-block align-middle">
                    <img src="imgs/icn-arrow-down.png" />
                  </object>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="casesDropdown"
                class="dropcontent bg-graydark rounded-[8px] mt-2"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/gamefi">Gaming</a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="pt-4 text-graylight font-normal text-base text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pb-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/nft">NFT</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1
              class="text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold lg:ml-4 xl:ml-8 hover:text-primary"
            >
              <a href="https://docs.streamflow.finance/" target="_blank">
                Documentation
                <svg
                  class="inline-block align-super"
                  width="8"
                  height="8"
                  viewBox="0 0 8 8"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M0.4379 1.28891C0.4379 1.6194 0.702293 1.85075 1.01626 1.86727L4.91605 1.76813L0.173508 6.51067C-0.0578359 6.74201 -0.0578359 7.0725 0.173508 7.30385L0.702293 7.83263C0.917112 8.04745 1.26413 8.06398 1.49547 7.83263L6.23801 3.09009L6.13887 6.95683C6.13887 7.28732 6.38673 7.53519 6.7007 7.55171H7.42778C7.74175 7.53519 7.98962 7.28732 7.98962 6.98988V0.54531C7.98962 0.247868 7.74175 0 7.44431 0L0.999735 0C0.702293 0 0.454425 0.247868 0.4379 0.561834V1.28891Z"
                    fill="#18A2D9"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden lg:block xl:hidden lg:ml-4 xl:ml-8">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div onclick="moreDropdown()" class="w-auto">
                <p
                  class="cursor-pointer droptitle hover:text-primary font-bold text-base text-graylight inline-block"
                >
                  More
                  <object class="pointer-events-none inline-block align-middle">
                    <img src="imgs/icn-arrow-down.png" />
                  </object>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="moreDropdown"
                class="dropcontent bg-graydark rounded-[8px] mt-2"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-graylight font-normal text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/integrations"
                    >Integrations</a
                  >
                </p>
                <p
                  class="pt-4 text-graylight font-normal text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance#about">About</a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="text-graylight font-normal text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pt-4"
                >
                  <a
                    href="https://streamflow.notion.site/Streamflow-Job-Board-public-019665299d73485e9098087ccf5ebe7c"
                    target="_blank"
                    >Careers
                    <span
                      class="inline-block lg:align-super font-bold text-xs mb-2 text-primary"
                    >
                      Hiring
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </p>
                <p
                  class="pt-4 text-graylight font-normal text-base hover:text-primary pl-6 pr-10 pb-6"
                >
                  <a href="https://streamflow.finance/contact">Contact</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden xl:block">
            <h1
              class="lg:text-xs xl:text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold lg:ml-4 xl:ml-8 hover:text-primary"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance/integrations">
                Integrations
              </a>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden xl:block">
            <h1
              class="lg:text-xs xl:text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold lg:ml-8 hover:text-primary"
            >
              <a href="https://streamflow.finance#about"> About </a>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden xl:block">
            <h1
              class="lg:text-xs xl:text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold lg:ml-8 hover:text-primary"
            >
              <a
                href="https://streamflow.notion.site/Streamflow-Job-Board-public-019665299d73485e9098087ccf5ebe7c"
                target="_blank"
                >Careers
                <p
                  class="inline-block lg:align-super xl:align-top font-bold text-xs mb-2 text-primary"
                >
                  Hiring
                </p>
              </a>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden xl:block">
            <h1
              class="lg:text-xs xl:text-base text-graylight font-bold font-bold lg:ml-8 hover:text-primary"
            >
              <a
                href="https://streamflow.finance/contact"
                target="_blank"
                id="mail"
              >
                Contact</a
              >
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="ml-auto order-2">
            <!--discord-->

            <div class="text-graylight hover:text-primary inline-block">
              <a href="https://discord.gg/ZC7URcQyM7" target="_blank">
                <svg
                  class="inline-block"
                  width="24"
                  height="24"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M14.2812 11.625C14.2812 11.125 13.9062 10.7188 13.4688 10.7188C13 10.7188 12.625 11.125 12.625 11.625C12.625 12.0938 13 12.5 13.4688 12.5C13.9062 12.5 14.2812 12.0938 14.2812 11.625ZM10.5312 10.7188C10.0938 10.7188 9.71875 11.125 9.71875 11.625C9.71875 12.0938 10.0938 12.5 10.5312 12.5C11 12.5 11.3438 12.0938 11.3438 11.625C11.375 11.125 11 10.7188 10.5312 10.7188ZM19 5.65625C19 4.75 18.25 4 17.3438 4H6.625C5.71875 4 5 4.75 5 5.65625V16.4688C5 17.4062 5.71875 18.125 6.625 18.125H15.6875L15.2812 16.6562C17.625 18.8125 16.9688 18.25 19 20V5.65625ZM16.7188 13.25C16.7188 13.25 16.0312 14.4062 14.25 14.4688C14.25 14.4688 13.9688 14.125 13.7188 13.8125C14.7812 13.5312 15.1875 12.875 15.1875 12.875C14.8438 13.0938 14.5312 13.2188 14.25 13.3438C12.5312 14.0625 10.625 13.8125 9.25 13.0625C9.25 13.0312 9.0625 12.9375 8.9375 12.8438C8.9375 12.8438 9.3125 13.5 10.3438 13.8125C10.0938 14.0938 9.8125 14.4688 9.8125 14.4688C8.03125 14.4062 7.375 13.25 7.375 13.25C7.375 10.6562 8.5 8.59375 8.5 8.59375C9.65625 7.71875 10.75 7.75 10.75 7.75L10.8438 7.84375C9.40625 8.25 8.75 8.875 8.75 8.875C8.75 8.875 8.90625 8.78125 9.21875 8.65625C11.0625 7.84375 13.2812 7.84375 15.1875 8.875C15.1875 8.875 14.5625 8.28125 13.1875 7.875L13.3125 7.75C13.3125 7.75 14.4062 7.71875 15.5625 8.59375C15.5625 8.59375 16.7188 10.6562 16.7188 13.25Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>

            <!--twitter-->
            <div
              class="text-graylight hover:text-primary inline-block lg:ml-[10px] xl:ml-[33px]"
            >
              <a href="https://twitter.com/streamflow_fi" target="_blank">
                <svg
                  class="inline-block"
                  width="24"
                  height="24"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M18.3718 8.22651C18.998 7.75663 19.5616 7.19277 20 6.53494C19.4364 6.78554 18.7789 6.97349 18.1213 7.03614C18.8102 6.62892 19.3112 6.00241 19.5616 5.21928C18.9354 5.59518 18.2153 5.87711 17.4951 6.03373C16.8689 5.3759 16.0235 5 15.0841 5C13.2681 5 11.7965 6.47229 11.7965 8.28916C11.7965 8.53976 11.8278 8.79036 11.8904 9.04096C9.16634 8.88434 6.72407 7.56867 5.09589 5.59518C4.81409 6.06506 4.65753 6.62892 4.65753 7.25542C4.65753 8.38313 5.22114 9.38554 6.12916 9.98072C5.59687 9.9494 5.06458 9.8241 4.62622 9.57349V9.60482C4.62622 11.2024 5.75342 12.5181 7.25636 12.8313C7.00587 12.894 6.69276 12.9566 6.41096 12.9566C6.19178 12.9566 6.00391 12.9253 5.78474 12.894C6.19178 14.2096 7.41292 15.1494 8.85323 15.1807C7.72603 16.0578 6.31703 16.5904 4.78278 16.5904C4.50098 16.5904 4.25049 16.559 4 16.5277C5.44031 17.4675 7.16243 18 9.0411 18C15.0841 18 18.3718 13.0193 18.3718 8.66506C18.3718 8.50843 18.3718 8.38313 18.3718 8.22651Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!--Github-->
            <div
              class="text-graylight align-middle hover:text-primary inline-block lg:ml-[10px] xl:ml-[33px]"
            >
              <a
                href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/streamflow-finance/"
                target="_blank"
              >
                <svg
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M14.8571 0H1.10714C0.5 0 0 0.535714 0 1.17857V14.8571C0 15.5 0.5 16 1.10714 16H14.8571C15.4643 16 16 15.5 16 14.8571V1.17857C16 0.535714 15.4643 0 14.8571 0ZM4.82143 13.7143H2.46429V6.10714H4.82143V13.7143ZM3.64286 5.03571C2.85714 5.03571 2.25 4.42857 2.25 3.67857C2.25 2.92857 2.85714 2.28571 3.64286 2.28571C4.39286 2.28571 5 2.92857 5 3.67857C5 4.42857 4.39286 5.03571 3.64286 5.03571ZM13.7143 13.7143H11.3214V10C11.3214 9.14286 11.3214 8 10.1071 8C8.85714 8 8.67857 8.96429 8.67857 9.96429V13.7143H6.32143V6.10714H8.57143V7.14286H8.60714C8.92857 6.53571 9.71429 5.89286 10.8571 5.89286C13.25 5.89286 13.7143 7.5 13.7143 9.53572V13.7143Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!--LinkedIn-->
            <div
              class="text-graylight hover:text-primary align-middle inline-block ml-8 mr-[28px]"
            >
              <a href="https://github.com/streamflow-finance" target="_blank">
                <svg
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M5.32258 12.5806C5.32258 12.5161 5.25806 12.4516 5.16129 12.4516C5.06452 12.4516 5 12.5161 5 12.5806C5 12.6452 5.06452 12.7097 5.16129 12.6774C5.25806 12.6774 5.32258 12.6452 5.32258 12.5806ZM4.32258 12.4194C4.32258 12.4839 4.3871 12.5806 4.48387 12.5806C4.54839 12.6129 4.64516 12.5806 4.67742 12.5161C4.67742 12.4516 4.64516 12.3871 4.54839 12.3548C4.45161 12.3226 4.35484 12.3548 4.32258 12.4194ZM5.77419 12.3871C5.67742 12.3871 5.6129 12.4516 5.6129 12.5484C5.6129 12.6129 5.70968 12.6452 5.80645 12.6129C5.90323 12.5806 5.96774 12.5484 5.93548 12.4839C5.93548 12.4194 5.83871 12.3548 5.77419 12.3871ZM7.87097 0C3.41935 0 0 3.41935 0 7.87097C0 11.4516 2.22581 14.5161 5.45161 15.6129C5.87097 15.6774 6 15.4194 6 15.2258C6 15 6 13.9032 6 13.2258C6 13.2258 3.74194 13.7097 3.25806 12.2581C3.25806 12.2581 2.90323 11.3226 2.3871 11.0968C2.3871 11.0968 1.64516 10.5806 2.41935 10.5806C2.41935 10.5806 3.22581 10.6452 3.67742 11.4194C4.3871 12.6774 5.54839 12.3226 6.03226 12.0968C6.09677 11.5806 6.29032 11.2258 6.54839 11C4.74194 10.8065 2.90323 10.5484 2.90323 7.45161C2.90323 6.54839 3.16129 6.12903 3.67742 5.54839C3.58065 5.32258 3.32258 4.48387 3.77419 3.35484C4.41935 3.16129 6 4.22581 6 4.22581C6.64516 4.03226 7.32258 3.96774 8 3.96774C8.70968 3.96774 9.3871 4.03226 10.0323 4.22581C10.0323 4.22581 11.5806 3.12903 12.2581 3.35484C12.7097 4.48387 12.4194 5.32258 12.3548 5.54839C12.871 6.12903 13.1935 6.54839 13.1935 7.45161C13.1935 10.5484 11.2903 10.8065 9.48387 11C9.77419 11.2581 10.0323 11.7419 10.0323 12.5161C10.0323 13.5806 10 14.9355 10 15.1935C10 15.4194 10.1613 15.6774 10.5806 15.5806C13.8065 14.5161 16 11.4516 16 7.87097C16 3.41935 12.3548 0 7.87097 0ZM3.12903 11.129C3.06452 11.1613 3.09677 11.2581 3.12903 11.3226C3.19355 11.3548 3.25806 11.3871 3.32258 11.3548C3.35484 11.3226 3.35484 11.2258 3.29032 11.1613C3.22581 11.129 3.16129 11.0968 3.12903 11.129ZM2.77419 10.871C2.74194 10.9355 2.77419 10.9677 2.83871 11C2.90323 11.0323 2.96774 11.0323 3 10.9677C3 10.9355 2.96774 10.9032 2.90323 10.871C2.83871 10.8387 2.80645 10.8387 2.77419 10.871ZM3.80645 12.0323C3.77419 12.0645 3.77419 12.1613 3.87097 12.2258C3.93548 12.2903 4.03226 12.3226 4.06452 12.2581C4.09677 12.2258 4.09677 12.129 4.03226 12.0645C3.96774 12 3.87097 11.9677 3.80645 12.0323ZM3.45161 11.5484C3.3871 11.5806 3.3871 11.6774 3.45161 11.7419C3.51613 11.8065 3.58065 11.8387 3.64516 11.8065C3.67742 11.7742 3.67742 11.6774 3.64516 11.6129C3.58065 11.5484 3.51613 11.5161 3.45161 11.5484Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>

            <a href="https://app.streamflow.finance/" target="_blank">
              <button class="bg-primary rounded-lg hover:opacity-70">
                <p
                  class="px-2 py-2 font-semibold text-base lg:text-xs xl:text-base items-center text-white"
                >
                  Get Started
                </p>
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>```
````

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: have you tried going into dev tools (F12) and selecting ignore cache/ pressed ctrl+F5?

Comment: Apparently it is not cache, tried that already :/ @JoSSte

Comment: What HTML do you see when you go into your dev tools. Are you absolutely sure you have changed whatever is picked up by mobilemenu()?

Comment: have you tried on different devices? - do all devices/Oses/browsers/curl behave the same?